# How to get data from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is elasticsearch query to get the document where owner1First is Donald and owner2Last is Brown. But this query gives all the documents as the result and doesn't filter.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test2/extract/_search" -d"
{"query" :
 {"filtered" :
  { "filter" : 
   {"bool" :
    {"should" :
     [{ "term" :
       {"owner1First" :"Donald"}},
       { "term" :{"owner1Last" : "Brown"}} 
     ]
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change to a `bool/must` instead:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test2/extract/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [        <---- use must here !
            {
              "term": {
                "owner1First": "donald"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "owner1Last": "brown"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Try again with all lowercase characters.

Comment: Wt do you mean by all lowercase? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Sorry I meant `donald` and `brown` instead of `Donald` and `Brown`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also, can I check if a term named owner1Mid is empty in this query?